# how to display a controller result in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i'm a young developer and i want some tips about code

That's my controller method

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TotaleOreComplessivo() {
     decimal somma = 0;
     var cedolini = _repoC.GetAll().Result;

     foreach (Cedolino cedo in cedolini) {
           somma += cedo.NumeroOre;
     }

     return View();
}
```

and that's my view

```
<table class="table-display dt-responsive" id="Ore">
   <tr>
       <td>Totale Ore Fatturate:</td>
        <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

how cani i show "somma"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a model which you will need to pass to your view. So your model class can look something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public decimal Somma { get; set; }   
}
```

Now in `TotaleOreComplessivo` action you will need to do:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TotaleOreComplessivo() 
{
   decimal somma = 0;
   var cedolini = _repoC.GetAll().Result;
   foreach (Cedolino cedo in cedolini) {
       somma += cedo.NumeroOre;
   }
   var model = new MyModel { Somma = somma };
   return View(model);
}
```

In your view you need to use the model as:

```
@model MyModel

<table class="table-display dt-responsive" id="Ore">
    <tr>
       <td>Totale Ore Fatturate:</td>
       <td>@Model.Somma</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Following the comment if you do not want to create a model then you can make use of [ViewBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) property. In your action you will need to do `ViewBag.Somma = somma;` then in the view you can use it as `@ViewBag.Somma`.

Comment: Thx a lot Izzy, but there is no way to show my variable "somma" without creating a model??

Comment: There are ways to show the response instead of using Razor and models but I think using the way @Izzy shows you will be less messy and use the strengths of the frameworks. Normally, you are better of using the praxis rather than rewrite everything yourself unless you have no other choice. Happy coding!